# Trying to transform Data from wide to narrow format

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So, I'm attempting to transform a DataFrame called Narrow from wide to narrow format and I figured pandas.melt would be the best decision for this:

```
wide = pd.melt(Narrow, id_vars='i', value_vars=Narrow.columns).sort(columns='i')
```

However I'm getting an error saying:

```
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional
```

This is a snippet of my data: 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Narrow.columns` includes the `'i'`-column, so you are assigning that column to both `id_vars` and `value_vars`. If you want all columns except `'i'` to be `value_vars`, you can just omit the `value_vars` assignment, because this is the default:

```py
wide = pd.melt(Narrow, id_vars='i')
```

From the `pd.melt()` [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

> **value_vars : *tuple, list, or ndarray, optional***
>
> Column(s) to unpivot. If not specified, uses all columns that are not set as *id_vars*.

Comment: @Ame That worked in setting it in a basic narrow format. Just the data is jumbled and not in a sensical format...

Comment: @Robert Farmer Yes, I did not include the `sort()` you had in your code, but that's just because I thought it wasn't part of the problem. You can of course still sort the resulting DataFrame however you like.